# Return different value from the Knockout component

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, components

I'm using Knockout and Typescript in my application.
I have some class:

```
class Address 
{
    State :string;
    ZIP: string;
    Street: string;
}
```

I would like to create component which will be responsible for updating object of this class.

Part of my app:

```
var addressObservable = ko.observable(new Address() { State: "aaa", ZIP: "12211", Street: ""};

<address-component params="value: addressObservable"> </address-component>
```

My component (html and typescript vm) looks like:

```
<div data-bind="with: address">
    <input data-bind="value: State" />
    <input data-bind="value: ZIP" />
    <input data-bind="value: Street" />
</div>

class AddressComponent<Brand> {
    public address: KnockoutObservable<Object>;

    constructor(params: AddressParams) {
        this.address = params.address;
    }
}
```

So, in shortcut, in my application I have some property which I send to my component. This property inside of component is bounded to some inputs.

The main assumption is that this componenent will put in "address" observable value:

1. "Address" object (if some properties are filled)
2. null (if State, ZIP and Street properties are empty).

I cannot change "address" object to ko.computed inside of the component. I don't want to change it outside of the component. 
Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly... Try to make your `Address` class' properties `ko.observable<string>()` to support two-way binding through the `value` bind. Is that wat you were aiming for?

Comment: Ok I can make them ko.observable<string>(), but I want to have Address class object as ko.observable<Address>() and put there null or entire object (depending on all properties).

Answer (score 0):

If you make the address' properties observable, you can wrap the address instance in a computed that returns `null` when all props are cleared:

```js
function Address() {
  this.line1 = ko.observable("line 1");
  this.line2 = ko.observable("line 2");
  this.line3 = ko.observable("line 3");
};

function App() {

  var address = new Address();
  
  this.displayAddress = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (address.line1() ||
        address.line2() ||
        address.line3()) {
      return address;    
    }
    
    return null;
  });
  
};

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: displayAddress">
  <p>Clear inputs to see address set to null</p>
  <input data-bind="value: line1">
  <input data-bind="value: line2">
  <input data-bind="value: line3">
</div>
```